# Modify dynamic created objects that are saved in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have multiple images that are created dynamically, and i want in some cases to change the image. i can save them in an array, but how can i change the image (load another image) by getting it from the array.
let's say that i have an array:

```
var ImagesArray:Array = [];
```

and i push to it **loader** objects, and want to change (load new) image of ImagesArray[0] or ImagesArray[1]... like:

```
var loaderNew:Loader = new Loader();
loaderNew = ImagesArray[i];
loaderNew.load(new URLRequest("../lib/NewImg.png"));
```

Thanks,

Comment: You're a bit confused about AS3. In the 2nd block you assign a **new** Loader to `loaderNew`, then you overwrite that object with one in `ImagesArray`. What does exactly `ImagesArray` contain?

Comment: I expect the second line should read `ImagesArray[i]=loaderNew;`

Comment: Then, I don't understand which is its problem...

Comment: my main problem, is that i want to change the images that are dynamically loaded in a loader..
in my code i was just trying to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to create new loader if you only want to change its image, here's an example of function to update image url:

```
private function changeImageByIndex(i:int, url:String):void    
{
    var loader:Loader = ImagesArray[i] as Loader;
    if (!loader)
    {
        loader = new Loader();
        addChild(loader);       
        ImagesArray[i] = loader;
    }
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
}
```

If you have bitmap, use loadBytes() method instead load(), here's example:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0xff0000));
var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
loader.loadBytes(encoder.encode(bitmap.bitmapData));
```

Comment: What in case i have a bitmap, can i change the image?
Thanks,